# Excel formula within spreadsheet to calculate hours worked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been struggling for some time to find formula for a spreadsheet I am trying to manage / create relating to working times.

Column B contains the start time.
Column C contains finish time.

When you work beyond 7pm in the evening the hours that follow are noted and required to be counted as irregular hours.

This would be calculated and shown in column E.

I would like assistance in how to calculate and find a formula for this function.

Within this spreadsheet I have hours worked in column D and I would like also a calculation to show when employee works more than 7 hours (column E).

Comment: please format the text for better readability ...

Comment: If an employee starts working at 6:00 pm and ends working at 8:00 pm, what would you like to see??

Answer (score 0):

If your values in cells formatted as time -hh:mm- :

In column **`E`** :
(You need to calculate times after 7:00pm -In Row 2-)

```
=IF(C2>TIME(19;0;0);C2-TIME(19;0;0); 0)
```

In column **`D`** :
(You need to calculate time between start and finish)

```
=B2-C2
```

If your cells formatted to text :
Use a conversion by `TimeValue()` function.